# packages : config, controller, dao, entity, form, model, util...are missing in my package

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate, spring-boot

I was following the https://o7planning.org/en/10683/create-a-shopping-cart-web-application-with-spring-boot-hibernate. But the packages config controller dao entity form model util are missing in my implementation. Can I know why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably that tutorial show you step by step how to create a simple Web Shop Application with database persistence. The classes and packages that you refer (config, controller, dao, etc.) are not automatically generated. You have all source code in the post and the explanation of each source and how works each one.

The SpringBoot has some interesting tools https://start.spring.io/ to generate start project with dependencies but its just a schekeleton for your application.